# How to Hide Bottom button when keyboard is open in kotlin?

Tags: android, keyboard, kotlin

I am having an EditText and a Button in my layout.

my button is parentbottom aligned. So whenever i try to type something in edittext button comes over it.

So to hide button i tried it as: 
`

```
fun hideButton(editText: EditText, button: Button) {

    editText.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
        val r = Rect()
        editText.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r)
        val screenHeight = editText.rootView.height
        val keypadHeight = screenHeight - r.bottom
        if (keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.15) {
            // keyboard is open
            button.visibility = View.GONE
        } else {
            // keyboard is closed
            button.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        }
    }
}
```

and called this function as:

```
    edText?.setOnClickListener { hideButton(edName!!, btnSave!!) }
```

but still no success in hiding.

Comment: Would that be a Constraint Layout or Relative Layout?

Comment: its relative layout

Comment: @Kriti, If anyone gives a solution, first you have to try it then if wrong gives comments plz..

Comment: Please share the layout.

Comment: There is one library which works with adjustResize. It gives you callback on when the keyboard is open or not. Maybe that can help :https://github.com/yshrsmz/KeyboardVisibilityEvent

Comment: Plus you can also use the event OnFocusListener();

Comment: @sarthakGandhi Thanks for your Library but i dont want to achieve this using any library. I want to do so by my  code.

Comment: Then you can use the onfocuslistener along with onclicklistener

Comment: @sarthakGandhi Thanks a lott!!!!! setOnFocusChangeListener helped me :)

Comment: Shall i post it as an answer so that you can mark it as correct?

Comment: yeah sure please add your answer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this :

```
  editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            if(b){
             //Hide button here
            }else{
             //Show button here
            }
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Edit : Kotlin version-

```
editText.onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { view, b ->
        if (b) {
         //Hide Button
        } else {
         //Show Button
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and in kotlin you can do so by 
        edText?.setOnFocusChangeListener(View.OnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus -> hideButton(edText!!,btnSave!!) })

Comment: I have edited the answer with a kotlin version as well.